# Javascript Form Validation with *

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms, validation

I'm using a name validation in Javascript. I found this code on internet. It's working fine.

I'm not getting why do we need to use the asterisk(*) symbol here? Code is not working without this also.

```
var pattern=/^([A-Za-z ]*)$/g;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Matches the preceding item "x" 0 or more times in ([A-Za-z ]).
Read this : [Quantifiers in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers)

Answer (score 1):

It's to matches any length of that capture group (`([A-Za-z ])`). I would recommend https://regexr.com/ if you run in to problems with regex as it includes a good explanation for all expressions